# How to iterate over an returned spring security tag using jstl c:foreach

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl

In my application using spring security, I need to iterate over authorities returned by

```
<sec:authentication property="authorities"/>
```

so I do this way :

```
<c:forEach var="auth" items="${'<sec:authentication property="authorities"/>'}" >
   <h3> Each- <c:out value="${auth.authority }"></c:out> </h3><br />
</c:forEach>
```

But it not work. This is errors in console :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/portal] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/layouts/standard.jsp'.] with root cause org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/resman/about/about.jsp (line: 40, column: 85) equal symbol expected
```

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign authorities to new variable and then do the loop:

```
<sec:authentication property="authorities" var="authorities" />
<c:forEach items="${authorities}" var="auth">
   <h3>Each- ${auth.authority}</h3>
</c:forEach>
```